# Parameters for createDeploymentSlot from the azure-arm-websites API for node?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm looking for a way to automate azure app-services slot creation for one of my webapps (preferably in nodejs). I have found the documentation for a library called `azure-arm-websites`. It looks like it provides me with the correct interface but the documentation is very limited. For instance i found a method called `createDeployment` which I want to use but parameters for this function are not well [Documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-arm-website/webapps?view=azure-node-2.2.0). Does any one know how to call this function properly to create a github deployment?

```
const client = new WebSiteManagementClient(credentials, subscriptionId, baseUri)
const app = new WebApp(client);
const name = '<filtered>';
const id = 'production';
resourceGroupName = '<resource_group_name>'
const slot = '<slot_name>'
const deployment = {
   deploymentId: '',
   active: true,
   status: 0,
   author: '',
   deployer: '',
   authourEmail: '',
   details: '',
   kind: '',
};
const options = {};
optionsCallback = function(){};
app.createDeploymentSlot(resourceGroupName, name, id, slot, deployment, options, optionalCallback)
```

I have no Idea how to fill the deployment objects parameters. For instance kind appears to be an enum but it has no further documentation.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: i'd just use any of the cli's available out there

Comment: The CLI for Nodejs does not support this and I want to avoid having to install python because of details of the running machine.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the help of the Azure CLI (node one, not Python). It is possible to define slots:

```
root@2e30e94ca7b7:/# azure webapp create -h
help:    create a web app
help:
help:    Usage: webapp create [options] <resource-group> <name> <location> <plan>
help:
help:    Options:
help:      -h, --help                            output usage information
help:      -v, --verbose                         use verbose output
help:      -vv                                   more verbose with debug output
help:      --json                                use json output
help:      -g --resource-group <resource-group>  Name of the resource group
help:      -n --name <name>                      the name of the webapp to create
help:      --slot <slot>                         the name of the slot
help:      -l --location <location>              the geographic region to create the webapp,
help:                                              locations found at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/
help:      -p --plan <plan>                      the name of the app service plan eg: Default1.
help:      -s, --subscription <id>               the subscription identifier
```

Comment: Yes but I don't think it is possible to add deployments which is also a requirement. Any how I have solved it with node. will post an answer soon.